# How can I do a recursive chmod only on directories?

Tags: linux, chmod

I want to change permissions on a tree on Centos 4 to add execute permissions for all directories recursively from a directory.  If I use normal chmod, files other than directories are also modified:

```
chmod -R o+x /my/path/here
```

How can I only affect directories?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Run `find` on `-type d` (*directories*) with the `-exec` primary to perform the `chmod` only on folders:

```
find /your/path/here -type d -exec chmod o+x {} \;
```

---

To be sure it only performs it on desired objects, you can run just `find /your/path/here -type d` first; it will simply print out the directories it finds.

Comment: Could you explain what {} \; does?

Comment: @Srekel see this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/339015/what-does-mean-in-a-linux-command

Answer (score 26):

See [Command line examples - chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod#Command_line_examples) in the Wikipedia.

```bash
# Remove the execute permission on all files in a directory 
# tree, while allowing for directory browsing.
chmod -R a-x+X directory
```

As added by Daniel: this should work in your case:

```bash
chmod -R o+X directory
```

Comment: This would affect the current permissions of files within directories.

Comment: @scriptmonster the line quoted is wrong for this case, but `chmod -R o+X directory` should work for the OP.

Comment: For those wondering about the difference, like me, it is that X will *also* apply execute permissions to any file which already has at least one execute permission bit already set (either user, group or other). In the general case the accepted answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /home/mydir -type d | xargs chmod ugo+rx
```

This works on CentOS6, which the above find -exec does not. Basically it just pipes the list of directories to the xargs command which sends them to chmod.  The chmod then sets universal read and execute (search) on the directories.  To do this for all users in home use sudo:

```
sudo sh -c "find /home/ -type d | xargs chmod ugo+rx"
```