# Recursive chmod only on {directories|files}

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

I'd like to know how could I change the permissions of all my folders recursively under a path (e.g. */Users/me/Desktop/main_folder*) and also change permissions to all my files under a specific folder.

These are the permissions I'd like to assign:

- All folders: 700
- All files: 600

There's a [question for folders](https://superuser.com/a/454797/411418), but I didn't find one for the files.

Comment: Pls read my Edit **URGENTLY**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

for all directories begining from `.` the current directory, and

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

for the files.

> Is there a way to know all the folders modified?

That would be

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

> I have to cd to the root folder first right?

**PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS FROM THE ROOT DIRECTORY**: you will make all executables un-excutable, including ls, rm, mkdir, and so on. The system will become unmanageable!!!

Comment: I have to `cd` to the root folder first right?

Comment: Is there a way to know all the folders modified?

Comment: Nou haha, when I said root folder, I meant the root of my app for example.